# Use {% with %} tag in Django HTML template

Tags: python, django-templates

I have a list of areas like this :

```
areas  = ['Anaheim', 'Westminster', 'Brea'...]
```

I would like to display them in HTML as:

```
<option value="Anaheim(Orange)">Anaheim</option>
<option value="Westminster(Orange)">Westminster</option>
<option value="Brea(Orange)">Brea</option>
```

So I try this:

```
{%for area in areas%}
    {% with area|add:"(Orange)" as area_county%}
        <option value="{{area_county}}">{{area}}</option>
    {% endwith %}
{%endfor%}
```

But the output is this:

```
<option value="">Anaheim</option>
<option value="">Westminster</option>
<option value="">Brea</option>
```

Where did I do wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe if you try only put the text next to the template variable like:

```
{%for area in areas%}
    <option value="{{area}}(Orange)">{{area}}</option>
{%endfor%}
```

I don't know why you try but is the same for me.

Comment: It's so simple :) I couldn't think about it . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `extends` instead of `with`:

```
{% extends area|add:"(orange)" %}
```